# How do Microtasks make it to the Microtask queue?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently researching the Javascript event loop, concurrency, micro/macro task queues.

I see that when using setTimeout, the Browser's Web Api handles the timer and passes the callback on to the macrotask queue to be run by the call stack via the event loop.

However, in the case of a microtask, such as a Promise, is the Browser's Web Api also responsible for handling and passing to the microtask queue?

If not, what is handling this process?

Comment: It's not specifically a *browser* or *web* API, but yes promises are a native API provided by the environment.

Answer (score 0):

The microtask queue is specified in the ES spec. The spec is implemented by JavaScript engines (most of them are browsers).

There is no such thing as "the Browser's Web Api", there are [the Web Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/?tag=webapi) which defines `setTimeout` and such, browsers also implements that spec.

Comment: A quick search for "Web Spec" did not yield much on the topic, but this was one of the links suggested: https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/script , the first line of this article: _"While the most common scripting language ECMAscript (more widely known as JavaScript) is developed by Ecma, a great many of the APIs made available in browsers have been defined at W3C."_ would seem to confirm the existence of Browser Web APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I see you added the link to the _"Web Specs"_, I notice the url contains the tag: _"webapi"_ (https://www.w3.org/TR/?tag=webapi). I think you might be mistaken about Web APIs, I'll have to downvote this answer.